# Form is opened behind the other form

Tags: delphi

1. I have an application **A** which is integrated with application **B**.
2. I am calling a function of application **A** from an Application **B** which should display a form in application **B**.
3. But the problem is the new form is going backside of the application **B**'s main form. (This happens for all the forms which are called from the application **B**.)

**What I tried in code till now:**

1. I have used [SetForegroundWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx) method. but the same result I got.

   ```
   procedure TMyForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
   begin
      SetForegroundWindow(self.handle);// set the foreground window as a top window   
   end;
   ```
2. I have tried using [PostMessage(Handle,WM_NCACTIVATE,1,0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx) but it is also not working.

   ```
   procedure TMyForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
   begin
      PostMessage(Handle,WM_NCACTIVATE,1,0);
   end;
   ```
3. I have used the `form.BringToFront` procedure call but still it is giving same result.

Comment: I think we need a much clearer understanding of your scenario. I for one am not at all clear on what is going on here.

Comment: It would be very helpful to see the code you are using to accomplish this.

Comment: @J... I am not having the code of integration but I can provide you with the code from where I am handling the calls from the application B.

Comment: If we don't know how the applications are related, what the mechanism of this "integration" is, how can we give you advice on it.

Comment: That would at least be a start.  If you don't have the code, how are you communicating?  Which version of windows are you using?  Vista and Win7 (pre-SP1) had issues with window z-order that were resolved with updates.

Comment: @J... I am using win7-SP1

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the mechanism of integration what i got from the code is just like loading and calling DLLs from any application.
Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Never mind. If you aren't clear on what your program is doing, then I don't think I can help.

Comment: As a suggestion, try getting application A to call the windows routines to bring the new form to the front. You'll need to allow Application B to return the new forms handle first, though. Check out `SetForegroundWindow` in Windows API

Comment: I'm having troubles understanding the relations between the two applications of yours. Can you please elaborate more. Providing screenshots or at least some image mockups of your applications windows would help a lot.

Comment: Talking about two applications would suggest that you have two *processes* — both A.exe and B.exe are running simultaneously. (And then I wonder how B is "calling a function" from A — out-of-process COM, window messages, or something else?) However, talking about loading and calling DLLs would suggest that only B.exe is running, and it's simply loading a function from a module that shipped with A; A.exe isn't actually running. Which of those two scenarios is the real one? Or is it something else? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: If have done something similar as you, all you need to do is make the form from app B a child window of the integration form from app A. something like this: `SetWindowLong(AppBFormhandle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(AppBFormhandle, GWL_STYLE) or WS_CHILD);  SetParent(AppBFormHandle, AppAIntegratingControl.Handle);`